# Is there a python implementation of a Face shape detector?

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv3.0, dlib

Is there an OpenCV-python, dlib or any python 3 implementation of a face shape detector (diamond, oblong, square)?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html

Comment: You can train a linear classifier for that. If the accuracy is good enough, cool . Else train a CNN. But first collect some labelled data. Let me know if you need an elaborate answer.

Comment: @RyanL link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Dear past version of self. With Deep learning; Convolutional Neural Networks,  This becomes a trivial problem. You can retrain Google's inception V3 Model to classify faces into the the 5 face shapes you mentioned in your question. With Just 500 training images you can attain an accuracy of 98%.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an implementation, maybe you can check out the demo by Face++. They also present the keypoints in the form of a JSON.
https://www.faceplusplus.com/landmarks/

Also, check this out for additional links:
http://www.learnopencv.com/facial-landmark-detection/

Comment: Hi Ayush, I am looking for face shape detection and not face detection. A face shape detection classifies a person's face according to its face shape eg a square face, a diamond face and oblong face e.t.c

Comment: Oh! My bad. Didn't read the question properly. Let me get back to you.